# communication between javascript and C++ code through web sockets?

Tags: c++

I have javascript (client - executed through node.js) and C++ (server) code running on Ubuntu (Linux) and I want this client-server to communicate with each other. Can somebody tell me how I can make C++ code work like a server or client using web socket? Basically, I want javascript code to send some data to C++ code, the C++ code will process on the data and return the result back to javascript code. I'm not sure if I this communication between javascript and C++ code can happen with out web socket. Any pointers in this direction would be of great help!

Thanks,
pats

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916217/standalone-c-websocket-server-library

Answer (score 1):

I *very recently* started working on a C++ websocket library: https://github.com/szmoore/foxbox

An example of a websocket server is: https://github.com/szmoore/foxbox/blob/master/examples/wsserver.cpp

I also have an example of a JavaScript client.

**Warnings:** The library doesn't support TLS, is based around POSIX sockets, and is still in development and probably horribly insecure.

So, whilst shamelessly promoting my own library I will also point you at [libwebsockets](http://libwebsockets.org/), a C library suggested in answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916217/standalone-c-or-c-websocket-server-library?lq=1

Comment: There is now [uWebsockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebsockets) which also has [node bindings](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebsockets-bindings).
This is better.

Comment: Update after I got an upvote: foxbox isn't actively maintained, but I do regularly refer to its code base and I did run one of the tests in 2020 so maybe it's useful.
I still don't think it's very secure, don't trust the preliminary DES implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have several choices. I am assuming your C++ server already has a websocket server running on it but if not, get Mongoose or the non-GPL fork Civetweb. Both are tiny bits of c code you build into your C++ program to add webserver,including websockets, functionality.

In fact, civetweb comes with a websocket example.

However, you do not need a websocket, just an ordinary socket should do. You'll probably want to send the data in JSON format to makeit easy to consume by the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a LOOONG time ago, but here is a gist of my set up that allows to have a communication between my c++ and Javascript apps; if anyone stumbles on this question:

1. I use TCP/IP connections to set up communication between a C++ app and a Javascript (Typescript) app. ZeroMQ (0mq) library is perfect for that. On c++ side you have libs like `zmqpp` and on the JS side you have `zeromq.js`.
2. After the data is received in JS land, you can use `Socket.IO` if you would like to have that streaming data available in a browser. Generally, you would have to forward the data stream off `0mq` through `Socket.IO` and then access it on the browser side.
3. Bonus: make the data format using Protobuf.

Answer (score -2):

On the Javascript side you will probably want to use an [XmlHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). This will cause the javascript to post an HTTP(s) request to your server. For the C++ server side, you can look at something like [Pion](http://www.pion.org/projects/pion-network-library) for an embeddable HTTP server or if you want to link into a full web server like Apache, you can use [Fast CGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/) to plug your server code into Apache.