# Having a c++ program call an html function/event listener

Tags: html, c++, polymer

I've made a simple HTML Page (using components from Google Polymer) that has a button which, when clicked, tells the browser to display a message.

The code for this button is:

```
<paper-button raisedButton onclick="document.querySelector('#notification').show()" label="Click Me!!"></paper-button>
```

This works fine, but I would like to be able to also trigger .show() on my notification if something happens in a c++ program.

Is this possible?

By this, I mean is there a way for me to call .show() on an html component from within a c++ program?

Comment: Best way I can think of is to create a constant async request to the server checking if the program has triggered some flag.  I'm not 100% sure on the details of doing this with C++.  It should be doable, but probably won't be very basic.

Comment: If the web page is being displayed in browser [control] embedded in the C++ program then yes and it should be pretty easy. If the browser is a separate application things can be a bit difficult. you'll need to narrow your question down a bit and be a lot more specific.

Comment: If your C++ program is a single instance for all web clients, you can have it write its status to a .json file and then your web app could continuously poll this file asynchronously (via ajax).  Anything else and the difficulty ramps up quickly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more about c++ to javascript communication than Polymer. But I came across multiple websocket polymer components including this one:

https://github.com/elierotenberg/x-websocket

So you can establish a socket channel between your C++ code and html page:

and attach an event handler to your websocket which triggers the 'show' method of the other component:

```
var socket = document.querySelector('x-websocket');
var toShow = document.querySelector('#notification')
socket.addEventListner('message', function(data) {

   /* you can get access to the message from c++ code through data object */ 

   toShow.show();

});
```

There is more info about websockets in c++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956174/communication-between-javascript-and-c-code-through-web-sockets)

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely. **C++** allows you to build solid, fast, and reliable programs, which is what you usually want from a back-end script.

The simplest way I can think of is running your **C++** program and tunneling its input/output through a net-cat network pipe (or other programs designed to pipe streams, check this for more example piping a program)

Then you can simply buffer your input, send it though a TCP pipe to your **C++** program (via Ajax or whatever you want). Process the input then buffer the output back to your html page using Ajax, or other methods.

```
./$your_prog.cpp | nc -l -p -q 5 $PORT
```

or

```
nc -l -p $port_number -e $program_name
```

If you're not a fan of `net-cat` you can use `netpipe` - [manual here](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2004/05/27/netpipes.html). You can also use `tcpserver` known to handle such piping: [here](https://pay.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/25sl98/redirecting_program_errors_to_stdout_through/) are more tools and examples.

You can also implement network functions into your **C++** program so it can handle network requests coming from your HTML page. You can use HTTP server libraries such as [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) to make your life easier.